# Telerik MVC Scheduler custom form buttons caption

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, forms, telerik, scheduler

How can I change the Save button caption in my custom Telerik Scheduler form?
I would like to have a "Book" caption instead of "Save". These buttons are not on the form and the appear dynamically when the "onAdd" event is called.
Here is my Scheduler:

```
@(Html.Kendo().Scheduler<SchedulerMVC.Controllers.HelpDeskRequestViewModel>()
.Name("scheduler")
.Editable(editable => editable
.Move(false)
.Resize(false)
.EditRecurringMode(SchedulerEditRecurringMode.Occurrence)
.TemplateId("editor-template")
)
.Selectable(false)
.AllDaySlot(false)
.ShowWorkHours(true)
.Footer(true)
.Views(views =>
{
    views.WorkWeekView(workWeekView => workWeekView.Selected(true));
    views.WeekView();
})
.Height(630)
.StartTime(new DateTime(2017, 6, 13, 6, 00, 00))
//.Timezone("Etc/UTC")
.Events(events =>
{
    events.Add("onAdd");
    events.Cancel("onCancel");
    events.Change("onChange");
    events.Edit("onEdit");
    events.DataBound("onDataBound");
    events.DataBinding("onDataBinding");
    events.Navigate("onNavigate");
    events.Save("onSave");
    events.Remove("onRemove");

})
.DataSource(d => d
    .Model(m =>
    {
        m.Id(f => f.ID);
        m.Field(f => f.Title).DefaultValue("Booked");
        m.Field(f => f.OwnerID).DefaultValue("1");
        m.RecurrenceId(f => f.RecurrenceID);

    })
    .Read(read => read.Action("HelpDeskRequests_Read", "Scheduler"))
    .Create(create => create.Action("HelpDeskRequests_Create", "Scheduler"))
    .Update(update => update.Action("HelpDeskRequests_Update", "Scheduler"))
    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("HelpDeskRequests_Destroy", "Scheduler"))
)
```

)

Here is my Template form:

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12">

<script id="editor-template" type="text/kendo-x-tmpl">

    <form class="form-horizontal">
        <div class="alert alert-danger" style="width:90%; margin: 3px auto; display:none;">
            <i class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;You don't have permitions to edit this item
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6 token">
            <label for="Token">Token:</label>
            <input id="Token" type="text" class="k-textbox" data-bind="value: Token" placeholder="Token ID" name="Token" />
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <label for="Start" data-translator="formStartLabel">Start date and time:</label>
            <input id="Start" data-role="datetimepicker" type="datetime" data-format="dd.MM.yyyy h:mm tt" data-bind="value:start" name="start" placeholder="Start date and time" />
        </div>
        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
            <label for="End" data-translator="formEndLabel">End date and time: </label>
            <input id="End" data-role="datetimepicker" type="datetime" data-format="dd.MM.yyyy h:mm tt" data-bind="value:end" name="end" placeholder="End date and time" />
        </div>

        <input id="OwnerID" type="text" class="hidden" data-bind="value:OwnerID" name="OwnerID" />
    </form>

</script>
```

And the form result is something like this picture:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Telerik help me out on this one so this is the trick

```
.Messages(m => m.Save("Book"))
```